# How to properly set CS for SPI applications on Arduino Due

Tags: spi, arduino-due

I needed SPI with CPOL=1 and CPHA=1. I read, that I could achieve this via SPI_MODE3. Further, I read to put the CS low and CS high code after SPI.beginTransaction(...) and before SPI.endTransaction() (See [official doc](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/communication/spi)). But the result does not look right.
Minimal example program:

```
void setup() {   // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode(52, OUTPUT); // CS high
    digitalWrite(52, 1);
}

void spi_transfer() {
    uint8_t buffer[] = {0, 0};

    delayMicroseconds(1);
    SPI.begin();
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(SPI_BAUD, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    
    digitalWrite(52, 0); // CS Low
    delayMicroseconds(1);

    SPI.transfer(buffer, 2); // Data
    delayMicroseconds(1);

    digitalWrite(52, 1); // CS High
    delayMicroseconds(1);

    SPI.endTransaction();
    SPI.end();
    delayMicroseconds(1);
}

void loop()
{
  spi_transfer();
}
```

[image: Oscilloscope picture of SPI traffic]

In yellow we see the CS signal (I use pin D52). In lila we see the clock signal.
To my understanding, this is not CPOL=1, as the Clock signal is low when the chip select goes low.
To my understanding, this is CPOL=0.

Is there a proper way to handle this? Setting CS outside of the begin/end Transfer would make the whole concept a bit superfluous.

Comment: it looks like the clock idles high ... it goes low before data transfer and returns to idle high after the transfer ... the second clock edge(rising) latches data